# How to animate state transitions in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

In my Blazor components I often render components based on either a conditional statement, e.g.

```
@if (_contact.IsCustomer)
{
    <SalesOrdersList Customer="@_contact" />
}
```

Or from a loop, e.g.

```
@foreach(var salesOrder in _customer.SalesOrders)
{
    <SalesOrderSummary SalesOrder="@salesOrder" />
}
```

When I change the state I'd like to animate the state transition so that the components fade in/out.  In the examples above that might happen when `IsCustomer` changes, or when a record is added or removed from the `SalesOrders` collection.

#### Animating adding a component

I can see how this can be achieved when adding a component, by the component having a CSS class that has a fade in animation that occurs when the component renders - e.g. as shown in [Chris Sainty's excellent toast example](https://chrissainty.com/blazor-toast-notifications-using-only-csharp-html-css/)

#### Animating removing a component

I can't think how you would do that when removing a component, because the component simply stops existing when that part of the DOM re-renders?

React has [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) that deals with the period of transition, but I can't find anything similar in Blazor as of yet?

Is there any way to do add an animation for the removal of a component in Blazor?

#### Animating Page Transitions

The other often-animated state-transition is changing 'pages'.  Again, I can't find way to do that in Blazor at present?  Effectively that can just be an animation for removing the old page component and another for adding the new one, but in some frameworks that's done at the routing level rather than the component level - I can't find anything at either level in Blazor at present?

Comment: one workaround is to keep the component alive but put if-condition on CSS visibility, width or height to show or hide it.

Comment: @Sorush that's a really useful idea - why not add it as an answer with a small example?  It might be possible to get it running on here https://blazorfiddle.com/ too

Comment: I posted a new answer.

Comment: I like [this youtube short series on animation using Blazor and CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTmZCu16LNU).

Answer (score 10):

Blazor doesn't cover this scenario, for this, you would need to use CSS. It's hard to give you a specific example as it depends on exactly how you want your animations to work and with what kind of style but I would suggest checking out CSS transitions and keyframes.

Here are some good resources

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

As you mentioned in your question handling items being removed is something I've not been able to figure out just yet. So I can't help with that unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Chris, glad it's not just me!  I'm going to need to buy you a beer at some point, your comments and blogs are really helping me up the Blazor learning curve!

Answer (score 6):

For the component removal side of things:

I added a [GitHub feature request](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10389) for removing on the AspNetCore repository.  Microsoft's Steve Sanderson has outlined that animating component removal should already be possible with the API the Blazor framework exposes, but it would probably benefit from someone writing a package to make it simpler to implement:

> The solution I'd expect is to create an animator component that
>   renders either a list or a single item, and incorporates logic to
>   delay the removal of each item so it can be animated out. Blazor
>   already has good primitives for templates components, so the resulting
>   APIs should be pretty nice. This would be essentially the same
>   solution that is used in other SPA frameworks.
>
> This is achievable in user code and doesn't require a built-in
>   framework feature. I'm not saying it's easy, but hopefully someone in
>   the community will find time to do it. It's something I may do myself
>   at some point but have other priorities in the short term.

[dazinator](https://github.com/dazinator/BlazorDeferredRemove/commits?author=dazinator) / @Darrell has taken that on and produced the [Blazor Deferred Remove](https://github.com/dazinator/BlazorDeferredRemove) Nuget package to do that.  I haven't tried that yet, but it looks like what's needed to achieve this.

There's now also the [Blazor.Animate package](https://github.com/mikoskinen/Blazor.Animate).

Answer (score 5):

Update: Rather than use the below, I've put an improved solution for this (doesn't rely on Task.Delay) on GitHub: https://github.com/dazinator/BlazorDeferredRemove

I settled on the following approach for handling fading out an element before it gets removed by blazor from the DOM. It's a workaround that uses Task.Delay and the compromise is that because I am using Task.Delay with a specified time in milliseconds this time needs to align with the duration you use in css for the transition - otherwise the element might be removed by blazor before (or after) the transition has completes:

Reusable Transition.razor component:

```
    <div class="@(ToggleActive ? ToggleTransitionOnCssClassName: ToggleTransitionOffCssClassName)">
        @ChildContent;
    </div>

    @code {

    [Parameter] RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] string ToggleTransitionOnCssClassName { get; set; } = "";
    [Parameter] string ToggleTransitionOffCssClassName { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter] int TransitionDurationMilliseconds { get; set; } = 200;

    public bool ToggleActive { get; set; }

    [Parameter] EventCallback<bool> TransitionEnded { get; set; }

    public async Task ToggleTransition()
    {
        ToggleActive = !ToggleActive;
        await Task.Delay(TransitionDurationMilliseconds);
        await TransitionEnded.InvokeAsync(ToggleActive);
    }


    }
```

and it's used like so from a parent page or component:

```
         @if (RenderThingy)
        {
            <Transition @ref="Transition" TransitionDurationMilliseconds="500" ToggleTransitionOnCssClassName="m-fadeOut" ToggleTransitionOffCssClassName="m-fadeIn" TransitionEnded="@TransitionComplete">
                <RenderThingy OnDismissed="@OnDismissed"></RenderThingy>
            </Transition>
        }

@code {

    Transition Transition { get; set; }
    bool RenderThingy {get; set;} = true;

    async Task OnDismissed()
    {
        await Transition.ToggleTransition();
    }
    private void TransitionComplete(bool toggleState)
    {
        RenderThingy = false;
    }
}
```

and css:

```
.m-fadeIn {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadein 500ms;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.m-fadeOut {
    animation: fadeout 500ms;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;       
    }
}
```

Comment: This only covers the remove state transition. What about adding new elements?

Answer (score 3):

### A workaround

we can show/hide using *CSS*. Just make sure handle `null` parameters that are passed to the component when it's hidden.

Let say we have component `Person` like below:

```cs
<style>
.container{
    display:inline-block;
    width:@width;
    height:@height;
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
}
.fade-out{ 
   animation: fade @AnimTime linear forwards;
}
.spin-in{
   animation: spin @AnimTime linear forwards;
}

@@keyframes fade {
  0%   {opacity:1;}
  99%  {width:@width; height:@height;}
  100% {width:0px;height:0px; opacity:0;}
}
@@keyframes spin {
  0%   {width:0px;height:0px; transform: rotate(0deg);}
  99%  {width:@width; height:@height;}
  100% {width:@width;height:@height;transform: rotate(1440deg);}
}
</style>
<div class="container @(IsShown?"spin-in":"fade-out")">
    <span>@(Name??"")</span>
</div>
@code {
    string width="100px";
    string height="20px";

    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string AnimTime { get; set; } 

    [Parameter]
    public bool IsShown {get; set;}
}
```

and we use it in another page/component like below:

```cs
<button @onclick="(_=>{isShown=!isShown;})">Switch</button>
<span>Left hand of component</span>
<Person Name="Jack" AnimTime="2s" IsShown=@isShown/>
<span>Right hand of component</span>
@code{
    bool isShown=true;
}
```

I used `@width`, `@height`, `@AnimTime` variables in *CSS* to just show possibilities are endless.
I should note that `keyframes` in Blazor component should start with double at symbol (`@@`).

See the live demo on [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/98pq34m3) and html+CSS only on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sorush/ontpkf3a/31/).

#### Another trick

In the case that user clicks on a button like *close* or *X* you can squeeze a 0.1s or 0.2s short animation in the period of mouse-down to mouse-up. Mouse-down triggers animation but mouse up remove the component. I coded this before [here](https://iamsorush.com/posts/how-to-create-a-simple-component-using-blazor-html-and-css-word-block/)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today.

To keep the last state in the document, I have written a helper component:

*DynamicUpdateComponent:*

```
@ChildContent
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool ShouldUpdate { get; set; }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        return ShouldUpdate;
    }    
}
```

With this helper I was able to do some animations between state changes, and therefore we can make a reusable component:

*StateViewSlider:*

```
<div class="slide-root @DirectionClass" style="@_contentAnimationStyle">
    <div class="slide @GetSlideClass(true)">
        <DynamicUpdateComponent ShouldUpdate="_isFirstSlideVisible">
            @ChildContent
        </DynamicUpdateComponent>
    </div>
    <div class="slide @GetSlideClass(false)">
        @if (!_isFirstTime)
        {
            <DynamicUpdateComponent ShouldUpdate="!_isFirstSlideVisible">
                @ChildContent
            </DynamicUpdateComponent>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool _isFirstSlideVisible = true;
    private bool _isFirstTime = true;
    private string _contentAnimationStyle = string.Empty;

    private string DirectionClass => CurrentAnimationDirection == AnimationDirection.ToLeft ? "dir-left" : "dir-right";


    public enum AnimationDirection
    {
        ToRight,
        ToLeft
    }

    [Parameter]
    public AnimationDirection CurrentAnimationDirection { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int AnimationDurationMs { get; set; } = 600;

    private string GetSlideClass(bool isFirstSlide)
    {
        var isVisible = isFirstSlide == _isFirstSlideVisible;
        return isVisible ? "show" : "hide";
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (_isFirstTime)
        {
            return;
        }
        _contentAnimationStyle = $"--animation-duration:{AnimationDurationMs}ms";
        _isFirstSlideVisible = !_isFirstSlideVisible;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (_isFirstTime)
        {
            _isFirstTime = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Here are some styles, which needs to be adjusted, dependig on the animation effect:

```
.slide-root {
    --animation-duration: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide {
    animation-duration: var(--animation-duration);
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide.show {
    left: 0;
}

.slide.hide {
    left: 100%;
}

.slide-root.dir-right .slide.show {
    animation-name: fadeInToRight;
}

.slide-root.dir-right .slide.hide {
    animation-name: fadeOutToRight;
}

.slide-root.dir-left .slide.show {
    animation-name: fadeInToLeft;
}

.slide-root.dir-left .slide.hide {
    animation-name: fadeOutToLeft;
}


@keyframes fadeInToLeft {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
    }

    100% {
        left: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOutToLeft {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }

    100% {
        left: -100%;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInToRight {
    0% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    100% {
        left: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOutToRight {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }

    100% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

In the end, you just need to wrap the state changes

```
<StateViewSlider AnimationDurationMs="500" CurrentAnimationDirection="StateViewSlider.AnimationDirection.ToLeft">
    <p>Make some State changes here</p>
</StateViewSlider>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try third party animation libraries like [BlazorAnimation](https://github.com/aboudoux/BlazorAnimation).

Answer (score 0):

In relation to **Animating Page Transition** part of this question ...

Transitions in blazor is not straight forward. You have to consider resetting state and preserving state modes when this is a requirement for instance when moving back to a previous route and need scroll position to be preserved.  Transition animations using css are a good way to do this.  There is a solution that allows using any transition method you choose (where examples are provided elsewhere in the answers here).

I would recommend you looking at this nuget package and github repository which exists to solve this exact issue.

https://github.com/JByfordRew/BlazorTransitionableRoute