# how to animate state transitions in Blazor when rendering a list of object with their own lifecycle?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I know that there is a post closely related to my question ([How to animate state transitions in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219984/how-to-animate-state-transitions-in-blazor)).
However, my problem is the following : Consider a list of toasts for instance. I want to display 5 toasts, they can be removed by clicking on them, or they remove themselves when their timers is out.

*Code simplified as example.*

**Component Toasts**

```
@inject ToastService ToastService

<div class="toasts">
    @foreach (ToastData data in ToastService.List)
    {
         <Toast Data="data" />
    }
</div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ToastService.OnListChange += RefreshList;
    }

    public void RefreshList()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**ToastService**

```
public class ToastService
{
    private List<ToastData > _list;
    public List<ToastData > List
    {
        get
        {
            var list = _list.Take(5).ToList();
            foreach (ToastData data in list)
            {
                data.StartCountDown();
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
    public event Action OnListChange;

    public ToastService()
    {
        _List = new List<ToastData >();
    }

    public async Task CreateToast(ToastData data)
    {
        _list.Add(data);
        OnListChange?.Invoke();
    }

    public async Task RemoveToast(ToastData data)
    {
        _list.Remove(data);
        OnListChange?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**ToastData**

```
public class ToastData
{
    private ToastService _toastService;
    private bool _isCountdownStarted;
    private System.Timers.Timer _countdown;

    public ToastData(ToastService toastService)
    {
        _toastService= toastService;
    }

    public void StartCountDown()
    {
        if (_isCountdownStarted)
            return;

        _countdown = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        _countdown.AutoReset = false;
        _countdown.Start();
        _countdown.Elapsed += RemoveNotification;
        _isCountdownStarted = true;
    }

    public void RemoveNotification()
    {
        _countdown.Close();
        _toastService.RemoveNotification(this);
    }

    private void RemoveNotification(object source, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        RemoveNotification();
    }
}
```

**Component Toast**

```
<div @onclick="Clicked" class="toast">
    Some message on a toast
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public ToastData Data { get; set; }

    public void Clicked()
    {
        Data.RemoveNotification();
    }
}
```

The above example work fine, cause there's no animation yet.
But now, I want to add an animation of the Toast component. So I modify the ToastData to first call a Hide method, this method will notify the Toast component who will add a CSS class that will animate the removal.
This works fine, until this happen :

- Toast component 1 start to animate the removal
- Toast component 2 start to animate the removal
- Toast 1 is removed, the list is refreshed
- Toast 2 is now Toast 1, the animation is gone, and suddenly it disappear
- Worst even, a Toast 3 would become Toast 2 and will animate even if not intended to be removed yet.

I understand that Blazor choose to reuse HTML, that's why in the Toasts component, all Toast component will always be the same. That's why I put the logic in the ToastData.
I'm guessing I'm missing something...

Any help or insight appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering components in a loop, the @key directive attribute is your friend.

It will help Blazor keep the relationship between data and a component instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-key-to-control-the-preservation-of-elements-and-components

Comment: The documentation is move to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/element-component-model-relationships